# Showing that a subset is compact.

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Let be $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set. Show that $B := \{ x \in A \ ; \ d(x,\partial A) \geq \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is compact.

I don't have idea how to prove this, I would like to a hint. Thanks in advance!

EDIT1: $n$ is fixed.

EDIT2: I was reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Spivak and there he assumes that $A_i := \{ x \in A \ ; \ |x| \leq i \ and \ distance \ of \ $x$ \ to \ boundary \ of \ A \geq \frac{1}{i} \}$ is compact for $A$ an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I supposed that $B$ is compact, so the intersection of $A$ and $\{ x \in A \ ; \ |x| \leq i$ would be compact and I thought that the reason for $A_i$ being compact, sorry for not put the full question from the beginning, but nevertheless how to prove that the intersection of this sets is compact?

Comment: It's false : for most $A$, $B$ is not bounded, so it cannot be compact

Comment: Can you use Heine-Borel theorem? $K \subset \Bbb R^n$ is compact iff closed and limitated

Comment: What does $\partial A$ mean?

Comment: $\partial A$ is boundary of $A$.

Comment: @Giulio, yes I can, the mtric space is $\mathbb{R}^n$  but I don't sure how to show that this set is closed and limitated.

Comment: @Giulio The correct English term is “bounded”, not “limitated”.

Comment: @egreg I am sorry, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $B$ is not bounded, so it cannot be compact except in particular cases. Just to make an example, let $A$ be an open half-space, say the points having the positive first coordinate and the other coordinates are arbitrary: for any $s>0$ you can find $x\in A$ so that $d(x,\partial A)>s$.

On the other hand
$$
A_n=\{x\in A:|x|\le n, d(x,\partial A)\ge\tfrac{1}{n}\}
$$
is compact. Indeed the set
$$
A'_n=\{x\in A:d(x,\partial A)\ge\tfrac{1}{n}\}
$$
is closed.

Suppose $(x_k)$ is a sequence in $A'_n$ which converges to $x$. Then $x$ belongs to the closure of $A$ so it either belongs to $A$ or to $\partial A$. However, the latter case cannot happen, because otherwise the distance $d(x_k,x)$ could be made smaller than $1/n$.

Therefore $x\in A$ and $d(x,\partial A)\ge 1/n$ by continuity of $z\mapsto d(z,\partial A)$.

Hence $A_n$ is the intersection between the closed set $A'_n$ and of the closed sphere of radius $n$, which is compact. So $A_n$ is closed and bounded, hence compact.

Comment: Wait, how can any point in an open sphere be more than the radius away from the boundary? Note that $B$ is defined in the question as $B := \{ x\; {\color{red}{\in A}} \ ; \ d(x,\partial A) \geq \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, therefore in particular, $B\subset A$. However, if $A$ is an open half-space, then $B$ is indeed unbounded.

Comment: @egreg, thanks for the answer, but now I'm with the same doubt of celtschk about your example.

Comment: @celtschk You're right, I misread the question.

Comment: @George Now the argument should be sound.